# Show products as posts on archive page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, archive-template

Usually products on shop pages show up with a single featured image title price and  add to cart button like this https://prntscr.com/ngn7o6 , and do not follow the themes original styles and settings

What i want to do is to show these as how a post in shown in any given theme like this https://prntscr.com/ngn7qw

i have tried numerous codes to override templates, changed themes with and without woocommerce support and customizing archive-products.php with loops from posts.php of the theme which works to an extent but somehow functionality breaks the only thing that worked was switching post type of products to post but i loose a lot of data that way.

i have tried making post manually but it was very time consuming as i am importing a lot of products through plugins which automatically import as products.

themes i am working with bimber and chipmunk 
i am an absolute beginner and learning as i go.

Thank you,

Comment: hi i was somehow able to change the post type = product to resources which my theme has a builtin support for , now i can customize the layout although some information is still not showing up and i have no idea how this happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to overcome this problem although not every efficiently, used elementor skin extension to create a template for loop, then used that loop in elementor template builder for archive.

While this does solve the problem i believe it is not efficient as it did slow down my website and cpu usage may be increased.

if anyone has a better solution without using any plugins please let me know.